# Do dictionaries have a has key method? I'm checking for 'None' and I'm having issues

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries, and I want to check if a key is in either of the dictionaries.

I am trying:

```
if dic1[p.sku] is not None:
```

I wish there was a hasKey method, anyhow.

I am getting an error if the key isn't found, why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `in` operator:

```
if p.sku in dic1:
    ...
```

(Incidentally, you can also use the [has_key](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key) method, but the use of `in` is preferred.)

Comment: You can also do this for lists, tuples, and strings.

Answer (score 0):

They do:

```
if dic1.has_key(p.sku):
```

Comment: @gnibbler: The question didn't say what version of python is used, so the answer was based on the typical widely used version 2.6.

Comment: @banx, deprecated means it is still there for backward compatibility, but you shouldn't usually use it for new code. `in` has been the preferred way for many years now

Answer (score 0):

`if dic1.get(p.sku) is None:` is the exact equivalent of what you're trying except for no `KeyError` -- since `get` returns `None` if the key is absent **or** a `None` has explicitly been stored as the corresponding value, which can be useful as a way to "logically delete" a key without actually altering the set of keys (you can't alter the set of keys if you're looping on the dict, nor is it thread-safe to do so without a lock or the like, etc etc, while assigning a value of `None` to an already-existing key *is* allowed in loops *and* threadsafe).

Unless you have this kind of requirement, `if p.sku not in dic1:`, as @Michael suggests, is vastly preferable on all planes (faster, more concise, more readable, and so on;-).